# Yii Routing Regex Multiple Words As One Parameter

Tags: php, regex, yii, routes

I'm using the Yii Framework, but this could apply elsewhere.

I have a controller/action I am trying to pass a string parameter to. 
This string can be multiple words and if so I urlencode($string).

Example: 
$category = "Chocolate Cake";
thus, urlencode($category) = Chocolate+Cake

How can I then get Yii to recognize this as a parameter in the route? It appears that I need a regex that can escape the plus sign.

things I've tried:

```
menu/<action:\w+>/<category:\S+>'=>'menu/<action>',
```

or

```
menu/<action:\w+>/<category:\w+>'=>'menu/<action>',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
menu/<action:\w+>/<category:[\w ]+>'=>'menu/<action>',
```

Just tested it locally, and it worked on my install ;)